# Change category meta title and desc in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to update category title and desc and add text on the category page?

I have tried searching the forum/google for this thing, but couldnt find a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEO by Yoast works. The titles and meta desc can be changed using the plugin.